# Unity, Bezier Curve with line renderer is not smooth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that uses Bezier Curve with line renderer in order to create some roads with curves. I did managed to create the roads with the curves that I want. However the roads are not smooth. Here is a screen shot of a road [image]

I'm using a Bezier Curve script that I have found in internet. Here is the script;

```
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

[AddComponentMenu("Physics 2D/Bezier Curve Collider 2D")]

[RequireComponent(typeof(EdgeCollider2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class BezierCurveCollider2D : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Vector2> controlPoints, handlerPoints;

    public int smoothness = 15;
        
    Vector2 origin, center;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool initialized;

    public bool continous = true;

    [HideInInspector]
    public EdgeCollider2D edge;
    [HideInInspector]
    public LineRenderer line;
    List<Vector2> pts;
    

    public void Init()
    {
        if (initialized) return;
        initialized = true;
        continous = true;
        smoothness = 15;

        controlPoints = new List<Vector2>();
        handlerPoints = new List<Vector2>();

        controlPoints.Clear();
        handlerPoints.Clear();

        Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;        
        controlPoints.Add(pos);

        pos.x += 4;
        controlPoints.Add(pos);

        pos.x -= 4;
        pos.y += 4;
        handlerPoints.Add(pos);

        pos.x += 4;
        handlerPoints.Add(pos);

        drawCurve();
    }
    
    public void drawCurve()
    {
        pts = new List<Vector2>();
        pts.Clear();

        edge = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        if (edge == null)
        {
            edge = gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        }

        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (line == null)
        {
            line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            line.useWorldSpace = false;
        }

        if (controlPoints.Count == 2)
        {
            drawSegment(controlPoints[0], controlPoints[1], handlerPoints[0], handlerPoints[1]);
        } else if (controlPoints.Count > 2)
        {
            int h = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < controlPoints.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                drawSegment(controlPoints[i], controlPoints[i+1], handlerPoints[h], handlerPoints[h+1]);
                h += 2;
            }
        }


        edge.points = pts.ToArray();

        Vector3[] positions = pts.Select(pt => new Vector3(pt.x, pt.y)).ToArray();
        line.positionCount = positions.Length;
        line.SetPositions(positions);

    }

    void drawSegment(Vector3 cPt1, Vector3 cPt2, Vector3 hPt1, Vector3 hPt2)
    {

        pts.Add(cPt1);
        for (int i = 1; i < smoothness; i++)
        {
            pts.Add(CalculateBezierPoint((1f / smoothness) * i, cPt1, hPt1, hPt2, cPt2));
        }
        pts.Add(cPt2);
    }

    Vector3 CalculateBezierPoint(float t, Vector3 controlP0, Vector3 handlerP0, Vector3 handlerP1, Vector3 controlP1)
    {
        //http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/
        Vector3 p = (Mathf.Pow((1.0f - t), 3) * controlP0) + (3 * Mathf.Pow((1 - t), 2) * t * handlerP0) + (3 * (1.0f - t) * Mathf.Pow(t, 2) * handlerP1) + (Mathf.Pow(t, 3) * controlP1);
        return p;
    }


    public void addControlPoint()
    {
        Vector2 pos = controlPoints[controlPoints.Count - 1];
        float hPosY = handlerPoints[handlerPoints.Count - 1].y;

        float mul = (hPosY > pos.y) ? -1 : 1; // check if the handler point was below or top of the control point and use that info to make sure that the next handler point is in the opposite direction
        
        handlerPoints.Add(new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y + (4 * mul)));
        
        pos.x += 4;
        controlPoints.Add(pos);

        pos.y += 4 * mul;
        handlerPoints.Add(pos);

        drawCurve();
    }


    public void removeControlPoint()
    {
        if(controlPoints.Count > 2)
        {
            controlPoints.RemoveAt(controlPoints.Count - 1);
            handlerPoints.RemoveAt(handlerPoints.Count - 1);
            handlerPoints.RemoveAt(handlerPoints.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

I have increased the "smoothness" variable up to 300, but nothing has changed. How can I fix this problem and have smooth curves using Bezier Curve with line renderer?